# Sorting measurements into different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a file with a few thousand measurements in the following format:

[image].

I'd like to sort these measurements, which are repeated, into seperate sheets so each sheet would contain measurements of a specific measurement type - like so:

[image].

Would anybody know, what would be an easy way to achieve this? The next and final step would then be to draw a graph of the measurements on each of those sheets.

I was thinking of using something like [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1174-excel-split-data-into-multiple-worksheets-based-on-column.html), but when I run the script from the site, a window with the message "overflow" pops up.

Regards.

Comment: Where does the error occur when you use that? Did you copy/paste and run as-is, or did you tweak for your data?  Also you'll have to add some handling where "Power Factor" knows to go to the "PF" sheet (I assume).

Comment: I don't know the exact place, since only the window, with the "overflow" message, pops up. Yes, I tweaked the three variables, which are in the beginning of the script. The name of the "PF" tab could also be "Power factor" like the values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the sheets made already? in which case, you could do something like this on the first column of each sheet: `=INDEX(ALL!$A$1:$A$1000, SMALL(IF("<measurement>"=ALL!$B$1:$B$1000, ROW(ALL!$B$1:$B$1000)-ROW(ALL!$B$1)+1), ROW(1:1)))`. Once you put the formula in, click `ctrl-shift-enter` at the same time. Then drag  the formula down to apply it to the other cells below it

For example, in the kVar sheet, the formula looks like `=INDEX(ALL!$A$1:$A$1000, SMALL(IF("kVar"=ALL!$B$1:$B$1000, ROW(ALL!$B$1:$B$1000)-ROW(ALL!$B$1)+1), ROW(1:1)))` then click `ctrl-shift-enter` and drag down.

more details [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3929-excel-list-all-instances-of-a-value.html).

Comment: No, unfortunately I have only the one sheet with all the data. The measurements from this sheet should be suitably moved to other sheets (as marked in the second picture), which would be created subsequently.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is VBA to procedurally create sheets. I'm not much help there, I'm afraid...